# Run function to update state on component constructor (and later)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a little combat card game as a learning excercise to understand React and in particular, state. In the game I'd like each turn a new hand of cards to be drawn that can be played so I created a function that draws the cards and called it from the constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            hero: {
                str: 2,
                currentStr: 2,
                def: 2,
                currentDef: 2,
                health: 100,
                currentHealth: 74,
                moves: 3,
                currentMoves: 3,
                cards: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                draw: 4,
                hand: [],
            },
        };

        this.drawHand = this.drawHand.bind(this);
        this.drawHand();
    }

    drawHand() {
        let draw = [];
        let cards = this.state.hero.cards.slice();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.hero.draw; i++) {
            const min = 0;
            const max = cards.length -1;
            const position = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            const item = cards.splice(position, 1);
            draw.push(item[0]);
        }

        draw = draw.sort();

        let hero = {...this.state.hero};
        hero.hand = draw;

        this.setState({
            hero: hero
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {this.state.hero.hand.join(',')}
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

When I create the App component however, I get the error

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.
```

I've tried reading around mounted/unmounted components but I can't seem to figure out what's going on here. I figure I need to call the `drawHand` method later in the rendering process when App is mounted - is there an event or similar I can use for this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**constructor** runs before the Component is mounted in the DOM.

So what you want is to execute the method in the [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method.

like this

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            hero: {
                str: 2,
                currentStr: 2,
                def: 2,
                currentDef: 2,
                health: 100,
                currentHealth: 74,
                moves: 3,
                currentMoves: 3,
                cards: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                draw: 4,
                hand: [],
            },
        };

        this.drawHand = this.drawHand.bind(this);
    }

    drawHand() {
        let draw = [];
        let cards = this.state.hero.cards.slice();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.hero.draw; i++) {
            const min = 0;
            const max = cards.length -1;
            const position = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            const item = cards.splice(position, 1);
            draw.push(item[0]);
        }

        draw = draw.sort();

        let hero = {...this.state.hero};
        hero.hand = draw;

        this.setState({
            hero: hero
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.drawHand();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {this.state.hero.hand.join(',')}
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems I was on the right lines but sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees.